# Adding List<T> property to ASP.net MembershipUser object MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have created ASP.net MVC4 application with Internet application template,
and want to add `List<T>` property to MembershipUser object provided by ASP builtin Forms Authetication.

This List property will be a list of StockPermission object:

```
public class StockPermission

    {

        private Stock stock;        
        private byte afterSaveAction;        
        private bool allowEditingStockDocs;
        private bool allowChangingUser;
    }
```

Therefore my MembershipUser will contain StockPermission objects 
which let MembershipUser to perform defined action with those Stocks in the List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add List property to our MembershipUser object or any other properties we can create custom MembershipProvider and custom MembershipUser classes describer in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Before you start trying to do something like this, it would be wise for you to read up on exactly what these systems are.  It's clear from your comments that you don't really understand them because you're confusing multiple systems.

FormsAUthentication has nothing to do with MembershipUser.  FormsAuthentication is only about providing a cookie for each web request to be shown as authenticated.  FormsAuthentication can be used with any kind of credential system.

MembershipUser is part of the Membership subsystem.  Membership has nothing to do with FormsAuthentication, other than your code will call into Membership to validate the users credentials, then your code will create a cookie using FormsAuthentication to log the user in.

The changes you want to make are related to permissions, and permissions are not part of the Membership system, they are part of the Role system.  These systems are separate for a reason, because they can be replaced with custom implementations.  and they have logically different functionality.

Finally, you can't change the MembershipUser, as it's part of the basic framework.  You could extend it by deriving your own class from MembershipUser, but that's not the recommended way to do things.  You should, instead, have your own User class which references the MembershipUser.ProviderUserId.

In short, you're about to dig into the internals of the framework.  This is not something you should do without understanding more about what this is.